# Rsync between two remotes

Tags: ssh, rsync

I need to execute an rsync between to remote hosts (reasons later), which is not supported by rsync (see man page). However, I think it should be possible using an ssh tunnel. I could not get it to work so far and I think I am doing something wrong. Have a look at the following snippet:

```
ssh -R localhost:50000:remotesource:22 user@localpc -f -N
sleep 5 #To wait for the tunnel to establish
ssh user@remotedestination rsync -e "ssh -p 50000" --progress --append-verify user@localpc:~/sourcefiles ~/destdir'
```

This basically hangs up during authentication of the rsync internal ssh. Just to test it, I connected to remotedestination and tried to ssh to remotesource via the tunnel and that worked! Is there anything rsync does differently which I am forgetting here?

Why do I want to do this? Despite general curiosity the thing is that remotesource is a computer from which I can only pull not push data and remotedestination has a only a shared account. Since there are frequent connection issues I wanted to write a script to restart rsync in case of an error. For this I need to authenticate via key files (no sshpass or similar installed). But I will certainly not store my private key in a shared account's home directory. Therefore, I want the authentication to happen through my local pc.

I hope somebody can point out my error, I don't see it :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got yourself tied in knots here!

The only time that creating a port forward to port 22 helps is when routing around a firewall. It does not help you avoid authentication. In any case, your tunnel only accepts connections from processes running on "localpc" so your rsync running on "remotedestination" can't use it.

If you don't wish to leak credentials into the shared account on "remotedestination", and interactive password entry is not possible, then things are a bit tricky. You could use keys limited by authorized_keys, but that's still not fully secure. You could use `ssh -A` to forward your ssh-agent connection to "remotedestination", but an eavesdropper with the same user access could also use that socket (this method is at least fairly covert, if you're not actually a spy facing real hackers).

Probably the most secure method is to initiate the transfer from "remotesource", using `ssh -A` agent forwarding on that side.

Alternatively, if the data isn't large or the incremental updates aren't the point, you could try `scp`. That can handle both remote source and destination, and will even move the data directly from source to destination directly, if it can. The downside is that it will always try to copy all the data.

Comment: I see, that's unfortunate. I'll think about that.Regarding the amount of data, we are talking several TB, that's why I need rsync to be able to resume after a connection loss.

Comment: My personal solution to that problem would be to write a little expect script to enter the password as I'd it were typed.

Comment: There is no sshpass installed, so how would you do it?

Comment: Expect is a scripting language for interacting with terminals like a user would. You could run it on the local machine.

Comment: Interesting, never heard about that. I'll give that a closer look I guess, thanks!